# C# and Oracle database connection

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oledb

Hello i have a project which the developer uses

```
conn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA; Data Source=example;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True");
        conn1.Open();
```

I have problem with that provider MSDAORA
and i think it's old
So i want to Connect to my database with another easy solution without MSDAORA.

Thank you

Comment: Any reason you're using OleDbConnection rather than OracleConnection or the Oracle-provided .NET classes?

Comment: no i just want to chage that connection string to another one easy to use and what i want to have if i use OracleConnection? any reference or..?

Comment: yeah sure,
i just have problems with providers because that project have on every button should be connected to database using that connection string

Comment: I don't see why that suggests you should keep using OleDbConnection at all.

Comment: no i won't if OracleConnection is easy to use and i just have to change connectionstring with the new Connectionstring using OracleConnection it's OK!
but i don't know about how to work with OracleConnection

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Oracle provider, add reference to System.Data.OracleClient assembly

use OracleConnection as in this example

```
string connectionString = "...";
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(your query))
    {
       command.Connection = connection;
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: i just have to change the ConnectionString?
nothing to change i the other codes?

Comment: @Oded i added detail Thank's for your advice

Comment: @Obama i'am sorry i don't here

Comment: Please don't indent normal text.

Comment: I clicked on CTRL + K in order to indent

Answer (score 0):

I used the latest ODAC (ODP.NET) from oracle and used the following string with an ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataTypes.Model1.csdl|res://*/DataTypes.Model1.ssdl|res://*/DataTypes.Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=YOUR_SOURCE_HERE;PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=YOUR_USER_ID_HERE&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: i'm downloading ODAC and i will try it! now
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you asked for an EASY solution, another option that is probably the quickest and dirtiest is to just try and change the provider that is in your connection string. That will keep you from having to go back into your code and adding references to assemblies.

In other words, in your original example, your connection string was:

*Provider=MSDAORA; Data Source=example;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True*

Try updating the provider to

*Provider=**OraOLEDB.Oracle**; Data Source=example;User ID=test;Password=test;Unicode=True*

For more information, check out http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/connection-strings-for-oracle/