# Oracle (SQL does not exist or access denied)

Tags: c#, oracle12c

i hope all is well
i have an issue with the oracle last version is 12c i have install the oracle in my pc i face problem when i want to connect to the oracle through c# language 
 the error which i get it is **([DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denie
d.)**

i don't know why? the following is the code which i try to connect to this database :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
namespace ConnectDatabase
{
    class ConnectDatabase
    {
        public void connect()
        {

            try
            {
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "Provider = SQLOLEDB.1 ; data source = pdborcl ; User Id = hr ; Password = hr";
                con.Open();
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The Connection Is open.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The Connection Is Closed.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: 1) If it is oracle, the why error message says `SQL Server does not exist or access denied?` 2) Are you able to connect to it via command prompt or terminal?

Comment: Why are you referencing `System.Data.OracleClient` but use `OleDbConnection`?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is wrong, it points to a Sql Server instance (SQLOLEDB). According to the docs

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308448/how-to-access-an-oracle-database-by-using-the-ole-db-.net-data-provider-and-visual-c-.net

the Oracle Database has to be accessed with its own specific provider.

If I were you, however, I would use the native provider rather than the OLEDB one, as mentioned here

[C# and Oracle database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365469/c-sharp-and-oracle-database-connection)

Comment: i also  use the OLEDB.1 as provider it's tell me the OLEDB.1 not registered on the local machine

Answer (score 0):

i fix it the connection string is the following

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=pdborcl;User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
```

thanks for everyone